# jangaroo loader index.html file

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

In the Jangaroo tutorial using Maven it states"include a Jangaroo application script **generated** by the Maven build process". This should be created in src/main/webapp/index.html, it isn't. Can anyone explain this, or what in the pox.xml is missing?
Thanks

Comment: Anything lacking in my answer? If you still have problems getting started with Jangaroo, feel free to post in Google Group Jangaroo Users!

Answer (score 0):

The misunderstanding here is that actually, the Jangaroo application **script** is generated, **not** the `index.html` file.
The idea is that your `index.html` usually contains custom HTML, e.g. loading your CSS or setting up some context. The only Jangaroo-specific things your HTML code has to do is load the generated `joo/jangaroo-application.js` script and run the application's main class, using its fully-qualified name (in this example, `HelloWorld` is in the top-level package):

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="joo/jangaroo-application.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  joo.classLoader.run("HelloWorld");
</script>
```

https://github.com/CoreMedia/jangaroo-tools/wiki/Tutorial-~-Deployment